# Intent filter browsable not work

Tags: android, intentfilter

This is my intent but not work. All browser start but my app is not in list, this is my Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.googal.com" android:path="/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: dude first read my question then insert comment . i know google

Comment: Try adding the default category to your second intent filter.

Comment: remove two `<intent-filter>` and merge up in  one

Comment: still not work for me

Comment: Can you post the codings of .MainActivity?

Comment: .MainActivity is empty . any code maybe insert in main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
               <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.googal.com" />
                    </intent-filter>
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.googal.com" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
```

Comment: remove `android:path`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="www.googal.com" />
<data android:pathPrefix="/"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Recent google changes have stopped this functionality until auto-verify has been enabled and the website has posted the app info. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70653427/android-deep-links-not-working-due-to-supported-web-addresses-being-disabled-by/76175738#76175738)